# Container being 'pushed' to centered position of body

Tags: html, css

Good day all.

This is maybe a small thing, but I am unable to find a solution to this.

My #body has the right dimensions to fill up the page, but as soon as I add my .Container class with the same dimensions, it still gets 'pushed' a few pixels.

How do I fully fill up the body with my container?

[HTML issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHh1B.jpg)

Comment: Did you try adding `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to your css

```
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried everything except that because I was not aware of the standard margin the browser seems to have.

Comment: @MwB Glad it solved your problem! have a nice day! :)

Comment: Thank you! I hope you are not unhappily surprised I choosed the accept for a different, this was due to his explination of the standard 8px margin as a reason why I have to add it.

Comment: @MwB i dont mind to me helping people means more then stackoverflow points ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that either your `body` or your `.Container` have some extra `padding` or `margin` that messes up your layout. Try using a proper CSS Reset to avoid that.

Comment: There was no margin or padding set. It seems like the browser added a standard padding/margin. 

But thanks for the reply!

Comment: "The standard padding/margin" is exactly what you want to avoid, and you should do it using CSS reset, since sometime different browsers have different "standard" definitions :-)

Answer (score 1):

From the look of it you haven't reset the default margin on the `<body>` that browsers apply which is usually `8px`.

Try:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Use a CSS reset to help normalize some of these things across browsers. A popular one is [Eric Meyer's Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, your also directly points the reason why I should add margin: 0;.
It worked

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 on your website and inspect the elements from there. Click on the container and see why it is being pushed. You have one more option you have the opportunity to see directly why it is pushed by clicking with the right button of your mouse in the white space where are the pixels you need to remove and click on inspect element on Chrome. Then you will see in the console what is pushing the container.

Comment: Seemed a standard browser thing to add a bit of padding/margin. Solved the issue by now, thank you anyway for the reply!